# document.documentElement.outerHTML returns a different HTML

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, serialization

I'm trying to make a js app that reads and checks HTML/JS code inserted by the user. I'm using document.[some div].outerHTML to retrieve the full html contained in that element.

But, I noticed that IE10 (and other versions of IE) modify HTML returned by .outerHTML property. In particular, it changes the order of parameters of any element. For example:

```
Original code:
<a id="test" class="myclass" name="test" href="mylink">link</a>
```

Becames something like:

```
HTML returned by .outerHTML
<a name="test" href="mylink" id="test" class="myclass">link</a>
```

As you see, the name and href params are reordered.
The odd thing is that, if I inspect the code via "view source" on IE, the code is correct and not-reordered.
How come this happens only with .outerHTML? I tried with other browsers, and only IE seems to have this behavior.

Is there a way to retrieve same HTML as "view source" by JS?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: inner/outerHTML serializes the DOM, it does not retrieve the original markup.

Comment: ^ and that's why you should *never* rely on the markup as a string, and write code that relies upon how the HTML is written etc.

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to retrieve the non-serialized HTML of an element; or, maybe, of the full HTML page, so that I can extract pieces of code from the full page html?

Comment: Ajax? I need the page HTML rendered by the user's browser; I don't need to send it elsewhere, for now.